# Problem with expression blend on 64bit laptop

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I'm trying to run expression "blend" on my laptop, but when i run project i get an error message with the following solution:

[image]

I don't know where I'm supposed to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from an expression blend help forum.
I solved the problem as follows.
Using regedit.exe I navigated to th registry path
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
and selected the key Platform. Platform had the value MCD.
Then I deleted only the value MCD. After this the key Platform was still there but empty. I closed Regedit, restarted my PC and run Blend 4.